# Dependency in traits inheritance

Tags: scala

In Scala, how can i add a container trait (like Traversable[Content]) to another one that extends the container (and thus has limited visibility of its content ?

For example, the code below tries to define a trait WithIter for a container requiring Traversable (of course, i have in fact other things in Container).

```
import scala.collection._

trait Container {
  type Value
}

trait WithIter extends Container with immutable.Traversable[Container#Value]

class Instance extends WithIter {
  type Value = Int
  def foreach[U](f : (Value) => (U)) : Unit = {}
}
```

Compiler (scalac 2.8.0.Beta1-RC8) finds an error:

> error: class Instance needs to be abstract, since method foreach in trait GenericTraversableTemplate of type [U](f: (Container#Value) => U)Unit is not defined

Is there any simple way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Instance extends WithIter {
  type Value = Int
  def foreach[U](f : (Container#Value) => (U)) : Unit = {}
}
```

If you do not specify `OuterClass#` when speaking of an inner class, then `this.` (ie, instance-specific) will be assumed.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the construct. You cannot say: new Instance().foreach( (x : Int) => x + 1). Why would you define it like that?

Comment: This construct can be useful when you want something that acts like Int but is incompatible--for instance, if you're defining currency or units of measurement.

Comment: @Thomas: It is not _my_ construct. Given the question's definition of `WithIter`, this is the correct way of declaring `Instance`.

Comment: That is the same as `trait Container[T]{val a : T}`. But new `Instance().foreach( (x : Int) => x + 1)` works not with the abstract type member but with the generic definition.

Comment: @Thomas One is a type parameter, other is an abstract type. They are not exactly the same thing, even if they are pretty close. In particular, you cannot refer to `Container#T` or `Containter.T`, because `T` is not a type, just a parameter. On the other hand, `Value`, in the example, is a type on its own.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use an abstract type? Generics are straightforward:

```
import scala.collection._

trait Container[T] {}

trait WithIter[T] extends Container[T] with immutable.Traversable[T]

class Instance extends WithIter[Int] {
  def foreach[U](f : (Int) => (U)) : Unit = {println(f(1))}
}


new Instance().foreach( (x : Int) => x + 1)
```